# Access Denied when i try to execute commands using TShell for connecting windows emulator

Tags: powershell, windows, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have to execute certain testcases for app in windows phone emulator.
I could able to launch the emulator
When I execute command in windows phone Tshell

```
open-device $ip(emulator)
```

Error:
open-device : WPCon failed to execute command "\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c reg.exe query
"HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"" (working directory = "") on device $ip: The operation
completed successfully. (S_OK / 0x0). WPCon.FunctionalException: Remote: Error: Access is denied. (Exception from
HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from
HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Answer (score 0):

Tshell works only with connected Devices .it does not work with emulator and to connect with Device,they should be OEM unlocked and Thsell establishes connection with Device using command open-device IP(of device)

Comment: How can I OEM unlock a Windows phone?

Comment: OEM unlock is done with the permission of microsoft.they Unlock the Windows phone only for their OEMs..OEM unlocking provides the Customozation of start screen,customization of settings menu and all..